# For loop in unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

Is there a way to tell the python unittest execute all assertion in a method and show all cases it fails, instead of stop at the first failed.

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_a(self):
        with open('testcase.txt') as ifile: 
            for iline in ifile:
                self.assertEqual(iline, 'it is a test!')
```

Comment: I have yet to see a unit test framework that accumulates errors and reports them all. It seems that the standard is to fail on first failure.

Comment: @TGH: I have; [googletest](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer) has `EXPECT` macros that continue on failure and `ASSERT` macros that abort immediately.

Comment: @user2357112 Ok interesting. I guess it makes sense since it's just a design choice made by the creator of the framework. I guess a common pattern is to throw exceptions when asserts fail, leaving it to the caller to implement their own tally of exceptions if desirable.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Python 3.4 introduced the [`subTest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.subTest) context manager. Your code will look like

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_a(self):
        with open('testcase.txt') as ifile: 
            for iline in ifile:
                with self.subTest(line=iline):
                    self.assertEqual(iline, 'it is a test!')
```

The ugly way to achieve this without `subTest` is to make `self.assert*` calls within a `try` block, print the errors caught, and raise the `AssertionError` explicitly after the loop if at least one test failed.

Comment: @lucemia subTest is unarguably the easiest way to achieve what you want, but you can also use `try..except` in a loop to print exceptions.

Comment: The problem with subtests is that `setUp` is not automatically called for each subtest, as can sometimes be necessary. It can however certainly be called manually as `self.setUp()` within the subtest.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can make a *data-driven-test* with the help of [`ddt` package](http://ddt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example.html):

> DDT (Data-Driven Tests) allows you to multiply one test case by
>   running it with different test data, and make it appear as multiple
>   test cases.

```
import unittest
from ddt import ddt, data

@ddt
class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @data('it is a test!', 'it is a test!', 'something else')
    def test_lines(self, value):
        self.assertEqual(value, 'it is a test!')
```

`ddt` can also have the [data coming from a file](http://ddt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#ddt.file_data), but it has to be a JSON file.

Comment: ddt-package [now supports Yaml-Files as well](https://ddt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html)

Answer (score 1):

Generally no. Unit tests stop at first fail. If you want to compare all lines you need to have a local list and then put the different lines into the list. Then assert that list length is zero. Or a local boolean variable.